# Rest-assured with testng

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

Currently I'm working with rest-assured api testing.  My sample url is http://eampleUrl/register/device?s=123&m=23ewre&d=123 
Here parameter s = device secret, m is mac address and d is device id. 
I want to know how to write the parameter in the above url, in code and how to use with dataprovider annotations. And how to check with assert command?

> {"msg": "REG_DEV_01", "level": "info", "meta":{} } this is the
>   success response

```
package com.qber.test;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

/**
 * Created by naveen on 14/12/16.
 */
public class testDemo {


    @Test(dataProvider = "circuitLocations")
    public void circuitLocationTest(String circuitId, String location) {

        given().
                pathParameters("circuitId",circuitId).
                when().
                get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/circuits/{circuitId}.json").
                then().
                assertThat().
                body("MRData.CircuitTable.Circuits[0].Location.country",equalTo(location));
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "circuitLocations")
    public static Object[][] createCircuitTestData() {

        return new Object[][] {{"xt@xt.xom", "xtxtxt"}, {"xt@xt.xom", "xtxtxt"}};
    }

}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for: how to pass arguments with `DataProvider` or how to make assertions in RA? Please edit your question and read documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

The *main* reason that it was not working, was probably the provided data, through the `DataProvider`.

**Extra**:

- Adds check for returned `statusCode(equalTo(200))`;
- Adds a few more body message validations;
- Adds `extract()` to extract the body as String.
  Which then can be shown.

Here is the corrected code.

```
package com.qber.test;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType;;

public class DemoTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "circuitLocations")
    public void circuitLocationTest(final String circuitId, final String location) {
        System.out.println("circuitId '" + circuitId + "'  location '" + location + "'");

        final String body =
        given()
                .pathParameters("circuitId", circuitId)
        .when()
                .get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/circuits/{circuitId}.json")
        .then()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .assertThat()
                .body("MRData.series", equalTo("f1"))
                .body("MRData.CircuitTable.Circuits[0].circuitId", equalTo(circuitId))
                .body("MRData.CircuitTable.Circuits[0].Location.country", equalTo(location))
                .extract()
                .body().asString();

        System.out.println(body);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "circuitLocations")
    public static Object[][] createCircuitTestData() {
        return new Object[][] {
                {"monza", "Italy"}
                , {"donington", "UK"}
            };
    }

}
```